# Who wins the AI-game?

Tags: strategy, game, palindrome

Anna and Isadora play a game by writing letters on the blackboard.

- In the first round, Anna starts by writing down the letter $A$ or the letter $I$.
- In the $n$-th round with $2\le n\le 999$, Anna first writes down a new letter $A$ or $I$ immediately to the right of the other letters.
  Then Isadora chooses two letters already on the blackboard and swaps them.
- Isadora wins, if at the end of the $999$-th round the $999$ letters form a palindrome (= a symmetric letter sequence). Otherwise Anna wins.

Questions: Can Anna enforce a win? Can Isadora enforce a win? 
(As usual, we assume that Anna and Isadora use optimal strategies.)

Comment: Nice to see a palindrome tag created and used at last! Great puzzle too.

Comment: Could I suggest you write point 2 as "In ***each*** $n$-th round"? Maybe I'm sleep deprived or something, but it took a bit to realise you didn't mean "at some random period in these rounds".

Comment: I think it might be clearer to simply say that the board starts with an $A$ or an $I$ (whichever, it doesn't matter) already written down. Then the first rule can be eliminated and the rule for rounds $2$ to $999$ becomes the rule for all rounds. The resulting game is isomorphic to the original. I think this is clearer because I initially was confused as to what a "round" was - do Anna and Isadora act in the same round, or are their actions considered to take one round each?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isadora wins with this strategy:

> In rounds $2$ to $500$, she can swap letters at random, or swap two of
>  the same letter.  It doesn't matter what she does.
>
>  Her strategy from round $501$ onward uses the following observations:
>  1) a sequence of three letters that is not a palindrome can be turned
>  into a palindrome by swapping the middle letter with either the first
>  or third letter, and 2) a sequence of three letters that is a
>  palindrome remains a palindrome if the first and third letters are
>  swapped.
>
>  2) is obvious: a palindromic sequence of three letters must have the
>  same first and third letter, so swapping them does not alter the
>  sequence.
>
>  For 1), we just need to check these cases:
>
>  - AII: swap first and second: IAI
>  - IAA: swap first and second: AIA
>  - IIA: swap second and third: IAI
>  - AAI: swap second and third: AIA
>
>  In round $501$, Isabella turns the middle three letters of the final
>  sequence of letters (the last three on the board after Anna writes a
>  new letter, which will be in positions $499$, $500$, and $501$ in the
>  final sequence) into a palindrome if they are not already.
>
>  In the $n$-th round, for $502 \le n \le 999$ , Isadora considers only
>  characters $n$, $500$, and $1000-n$.  She can apply observations 1 and
>  2 to ensure that these three letters could be part of a palindrome:
>  that is, that the letter in position $n$ is the same as the letter in
>  position $1000-n$.  If Isadora does this every round until the end of
>  the game, this guarantees that after round $n$, the letters from
>  position $1000-n$ to position $n$ on the board are palindromic.  After
>  the $999$-th round, all the letters on the board will be a palindrome.
>
>
>  Anna cannot do anything to stop this strategy.  On her turn she cannot
>  alter the existing sequence except to append a new letter, and
>  whichever letter she appends on round $n$, Isadora can ensure that the
>  letters from $1000-n$ to $n$ are a palindrome.

Answer (score 3):

Isadora will never

> lose

Because:

> She skips the first 500 turns(because 500th character is the middle one)
>  Then, starting from turn 501(and every other turn $t$) she should start making palindromes of the last $2(t-500) + 1$ characters.
>  For $t = 501$ we get: $2(501-500) + 1 = 3$ last characters that she should form into a palindrome.
>  So let's say 499th character is $A$, 500th is $A$ and 501st is $I$. In this case she should swap 500th and 501st characters and last 3 characters will form a palindrome. Repeat for every next step.
>  If Anna puts a letter that will make a palindrome of last $2(t-500)+1$ characters(so in previous example if 501st char would be $A$), Isadora should do nothing and wait for the next move.
>  If Anna puts a letter that will not make a palindrome of last $2(t-500)+1$ characters, Isadora should do one of the following:
>  If $charAt(500-(t-500)) \neq charAt(t)$, then
>  If $charAt(500) \neq charAt(t)$, then
>  Swap characters 500 and t,
>  Else
>  Swap characters (500-(t-500)) and t
>  And she will get a palindrome again.

Answer (score 2):

Isadora can eventually

> **WIN**

- Lets assume A is 0 and I=1
- Lets note a whichever sequence 00110... = AeI where e is the middle of sequence since 999 is odd

regardless of Ana's final sequence , Isadora can switch each two digits she wants after each round , n-1 times , it means an even number of swaps , that means the final sequence we have is :

> - **(AeI) $\oplus$ C**

When isadora swaps the 2nd and 4th digits this operation takes place:

> - abcd $\oplus$ 0101

When isadora swaps the fifth and 4th digits after anna's next move this operation would take place:

> - abcde $\oplus$ 0101 $\oplus$ 00011 = abcde $\oplus$ 01001

That does mean

> - **C contains an even occurence of 1**

lets sepatare C into ( C1 c C2 )

AeI $\oplus$ C = (A $\oplus$ C1) (e $\oplus$ c) (I $\oplus$ C2)

The winning condition for Isadora is :

> - **A $\oplus$  C1 = I $\oplus$ C2**

there s many solutions can verify this equation , lets take an example of C1=I and C2=A

if the number of 1 is odd in C1 C2 we make c=1 and it wouldnt change anything since it is the middle of an odd sequence.